# ProgrammingError at /admin/group_manager/automaticgroup/

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have encountered this problem on my django admin page, I really don't understand what is happening but I'm unable to view my table content on the admin page in the django server and it is returning errors.
I succeeded in doing migrations, I wonder if it did migrations well but then they confirmed that no new migrations was detected.
So, this is what happens, after running:

> > python manage.py runserver
> >     It returns this:
> >     Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> >     and when I click on it and go to the admin section "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin" and click on my newly created table, it returns this error page.

Please could someone help me :-(

[This is a screenshot of my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8CxQ.png)

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/group_manager/automaticgroup/

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home.apps.HomeConfig',
 'profile_manager.apps.ProfileManagerConfig',
 'group_manager.apps.GroupManagerConfig',
 'trip_manager.apps.TripManagerConfig',
 'relationship_manager.apps.RelationshipManagerConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',`enter code here`
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  209.         res = self._query(query)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _query
  315.         db.query(q)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in query
  239.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1146, "Table 'opentravels.group_manager_automaticgroup' doesn't exist")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1672.             cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in get_changelist_instance
  744.             sortable_by,

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in __init__
  82.         self.get_results(request)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in get_results
  210.         result_count = paginator.count

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __get__
  80.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py" in count
  91.             return c()

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in count
  392.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_count
  504.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_aggregation
  489.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1097.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  209.         res = self._query(query)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _query
  315.         db.query(q)

File "C:\Users\Glory\Desktop\django\opentravels\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in query
  239.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/group_manager/automaticgroup/
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'opentravels.group_manager_automaticgroup' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'opentravels.group_manager_automaticgroup' doesn't exist")
You are clearly missing table, as you run makemigrations you should run migrate afterwards

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your source code, so that we can help you.

Comment: Below is my models.py:

from django.db import models


# Create your models here


class AutomaticGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=64)

Answer (score 0):

cross check  if your database table is correctly named "group_manager_automaticgroup". It may be named differently [It should be named like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9lQI.png)